# MongoDB: Restoring a database without a backup

Tags: mongodb, restore, recovery

I found that the database all collection was missing(maybe hacked or manualy removed or server hard drive issue -> PC: windows10).

Mongo is work/configured/installed on my local server(PC: windows 10)
The last backup was made 5 months ago (( (comand: ./mongodump.exe --host= --port= --db=  --out=D:/backup/file.json)

There is a any way (without backup) to restore/recover previous state of mongoDB ? (for example, a few days earlier or something) when was the data.
The day before the DB data was fine (all collection)

In the root folder(where installed mongoDB) there are such files (see on screenshots)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZw1J.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phliD.jpg)

when I noticed there was no data I immediately stopped mongo and the application.

Comment: You can try the `--repair` option. Otherwise: no backup - no mercy!